# Why add new property on prototype is different from replace the prototype object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototype

If I have a JavaScript constructor function:

```js
function Foo() {}
Foo.prototype.bar = 123
```

Now I create a new object from Foo and change the bar property on prototype object.

```js
const foo = new Foo()
Foo.prototype.bar = 321
console.log(foo.bar) // 321
```

But If I replace `Foo.prototype` with a object like this:

```js
const foo = new Foo()
Foo.prototype = { bar: 321 }
console.log(foo.bar) // 123
```

Why the two code snippets' output is different?

Comment: Because instances already created reference the old *constructor.prototype* object via their internal `[[Prototype]]` property. That value is assigned when the instance is created. To change that, use [*Object.setPrototypeOf*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) but read the warnings (it's not a good thing to do).

Comment: `foo` points to the *prototype object*, not to `Foo.prototype`. If you replace `Foo.prototype`, `foo` will still point at the old *object*. Same as `let a = {}; let b = a; a = {}`.